# First and second projection, definition and/or motivation for name

Tags: graphing-functions, projective-geometry

I have read that in the ordered pair $z=(x_1,x_2)$, an element of a direct product $Z=X_1 \times X_2$ of sets $X_1$ and $X_2$, the element $x_1$ is called the first projection and $x_2$ is called the second projection, is this just by definition, or is there a more meaningful reason for these names?

they can then be denoted pr$_1z$ and pr$_2z$

should i just accept this, or maybe i can think of it in a different way to being just names?

p.s. i looked up the mathjax stuff for this, tell me if it is alright, thanks!

Comment: The name projecton comes from the fact that if you take for istance $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R$ and a 3-D object $X$, it's image on $\Bbb R^2$ of $X$ is what is usually called the (orthogonal) projection of $X$. This is what you see for instance in maps which are a (flat) 2-D representations of the 3-D world

Comment: i think i understand from a logical point of view. so we take the 3D object and flatten it. but for the 2d representation of the 3d world, lets say we are viewing it from above(Z direction) we flatten it and retain the X-Y direction, this means that all the greatest z are visible(ignoring invisible gases and stuff), how is that?

Comment: well, you flatten the entire vertical perpendicular line, above and under the plane to a single point. Of course this is not what you do in the real world but, hey!, it's just where it gets the name from. :)

Comment: @AndreaMori oh, woops, i got too into it, of course it is just math haha, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is from the definition. However you may be intereseting in that what it come from or why we called it by this name.

In fact: Pick a point $(x,y)$ from the space $\Bbb R^2$, you will find that $x$ is just the projection of the point $(x,y)$, and $y$ is also!

Comment: so we pull that x from the point $(x,y)$ and that is why it is a projection? because we are pulling that one factor out? $x$ being pulled out is sort of an abstraction of position, i think that makes sense